# NSString String Format Specifiers problem

Tags: c, objective-c, printf, nsstring

I wonder what's the problem for these format specifiers which will crash when called with `initWithFormat:arguments`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // success cases
    [self log:@"%p"];
    [self log:@"% P"];
    [self log:@"% P% o"];
    [self log:@"% P% o %"];
    // crash cases
    [self log:@"%P%o%P"];
    [self log:@"% P% o % P"];
    return YES;
}

- (void)log:(NSString *)format, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    NSString *logLine = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args];
    va_end(args);
    NSLog(@"%@", logLine);
}
```

Comment: You need of course to supply arguments - this will print gibberish as there are no arguments and will read from some random place which can cause all sorts of trouble and may be the reason you have a crash. Then (upper case) ```P``` is not a valid format specifier so again anything can happen.

Comment: @skaak so here you mean this could just be undefined behaviors that anything is possible?

Comment: I think you could probably figure it out if you had deep technical knowledge of how ```printf``` handles e.g. the (unknown) upper case ```P``` or the absence of any arguments, but it is a bit of a moot exercise. If you use it like that you will run into trouble soon as you do. So I mean a bit of both, since you use invalid format specifiers you will get undefined behaviour and anything is possible.